# React router v6.0.0-beta.5

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I update my react router from v6.0.0-beta.0 to v6.0.0-beta.5,
And when using nested routers like this:

App.js:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="users/*" element={<Users />} />
</Routes>
```

In Users.js

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="me" element={<Me />} />
    <Route path="all" element={<All />} />
</Routes>
```

In the v6.0.0-beta.0 everything worked well after my update to v6.0.0-beta.5 when I click on my Link(me or all) first time it work  after the first click I get something like that:
http://localhost:3001/users/me/me/all/all/all

I cant understand if this is a bug from the update or maybe something changed in the update and I am doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be fixed in v6.0.0-beta.7.